# Using loop to select data and display in div MySql php

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, database

I have a table in MySql table with many rows of records (existingbankproducts table):

[image]

The code I use to select is from the database is below:

```
$stmt2 = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM applicantpersonaldetails apd "
        . "INNER JOIN existingbankproducts ext ON apd.ApplicantID = ext.ApplicantID "
        . "WHERE apd.AccountID ='{$accountId}' AND apd.applicantType ='main';");

$stmt2->execute();

if ($stmt2->rowCount() > 0) {
    while ($row = $stmt2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {



        ?>
        <?php
    }
} else {
    ?>
    <div class="">
        <div class="alert alert-warning">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> &nbsp; No Data Found ...
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

I want to select them and insert to my HTML table, the code is below:

```
<table>
<tr>
<th>Financial Institution</th>
<th>Product Type</th>
<th>Balance</th>
<th>Monthly Commitment</th>


</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type = "text" name = "finanIns1" id = "finanIns1" value = ""readonly></td>
<td>
<input list = "proTypeList" name = "proType1" id = "proType1"readonly >

</td>
<td id = "balance"><input type = "number" name = "balance1" id = "balance1" value = "" min = "0"readonly></td>
<td id = "MonthyComm"><input type = "number" name = "monthlyComm1" id = "monthlyComm1" value = "" min = "0"readonly></td>

</tr>

<tr>
<td><input type = "text" name = "finanIns2" id = "finanIns2" value = ""readonly></td>
<td>
<input list = "proTypeList" name = "proType2" id = "proType2" readonly>

</td>
<td id = "balance"><input type = "number" name = "balance2" id = "balance2" value = "" min = "0"readonly></td>
<td id = "MonthyComm"><input type = "number" name = "monthlyComm2" id = "monthlyComm2" value = "" min = "0"readonly></td>

</tr>

</table>
```

Actually, there are more rows, this is an example.

Also, I put `value="<?php echo $row['Financialinstitution'] " ?>`  as an example, However, all the records are coming out.

Is there any way to display the result according to the HTML table in order.

Comment: try to provide only shortest possible required code instead of ctrl+a & ctrl+v.

Comment: use order by clause in your select query, to get the sorted output and loop over it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1st :** You need to loop the record set like this

**2nd :** your input value should filled with right column like this

```
<input type = "text" name = "finanIns1" id = "finanIns1" value="<?php echo $row['Financialinstitution']; ?>" readonly>
```

**Note :**   you need to echo the each column `desired td input` .  i have echo only one column

**3rd :**  using prepared statement is good . as well you need to use  bindparam . like this

```
$stmt2 = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM applicantpersonaldetails apd "
        . "INNER JOIN existingbankproducts ext ON apd.ApplicantID = ext.ApplicantID "
        . "WHERE apd.AccountID =:accountId AND apd.applicantType ='main';");

$stmt2->bindParam(':accountId', $accountId, PDO::PARAM_INT); 
//if account id data type is varchar change the last parameter to `PDO::PARAM_str`
$stmt2->execute();
```

**PHP :**

```
if ($stmt2->rowCount() > 0) {

    ?>
    <table>
    <tr>
    <th>Financial Institution</th>
    <th>Product Type</th>
    <th>Balance</th>
    <th>Monthly Commitment</th> 
    </tr>
    <?php


    while ($row = $stmt2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    ?>
     <tr>
        <td><input type = "text" name = "finanIns1" id = "finanIns1" value="<?php echo $row['Financialinstitution']; ?>" readonly></td>
        // like above td you need to echo all your data for following td 
        <td>
        <input list = "proTypeList" name = "proType1" id = "proType1" readonly >

        </td>
        <td id = "balance"><input type = "number" name = "balance1" id = "balance1" value = "" min = "0"readonly></td>
        <td id = "MonthyComm"><input type = "number" name = "monthlyComm1" id = "monthlyComm1" value = "" min = "0"readonly></td>

    </tr>

        <?php
    }
} else {
    ?>
    <div class="">
        <div class="alert alert-warning">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> &nbsp; No Data Found ...
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whatever i understand from your question you can look like below:

```
if ($stmt2->rowCount() > 0) {
    while ($row = $stmt2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
?>
<tr>
<td><input type = "text" name = "finanIns1" id = "finanIns1" value = "<?php $row['columnName']?>" readonly></td>
<td>
<input list = "proTypeList" name = "proType1" id = "proType1"readonly >

</td>
<td id = "balance"><input type = "number" name = "balance1" id = "balance1" value = "<?php $row['columnName']?>" min = "0"readonly></td>
<td id = "MonthyComm"><input type = "number" name = "monthlyComm1" id = "monthlyComm1" value = "" min = "0"readonly></td>

</tr>

<tr>
<td><input type = "text" name = "finanIns2" id = "finanIns2" value = "<?php $row['columnName']?>" readonly></td>
<td>
<input list = "proTypeList" name = "proType2" id = "proType2" readonly>

</td>
<td id = "balance"><input type = "number" name = "balance2" id = "balance2" value = "<?php $row['columnName']?>" min = "0"readonly></td>
<td id = "MonthyComm"><input type = "number" name = "monthlyComm2" id = "monthlyComm2" value = "<?php $row['columnName']?>" min = "0"readonly></td>

</tr>
<?php


        ?>
        <?php
    }
```